# date variable not resolve in log4j2.xml when using log4j 2.0 in standalone java app under osx

Tags: java, variables, date, configuration-files, log4j2

I'm using log4j 2 in my standalone java app.  However, I'm struggling with the date variable in the log4j2.xml configuration. It's not getting resolved.

Here is my log4j2.xml configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="OFF">
  <appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
    <File name="File" fileName="logs/Server-${date}.log">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>       
    </File>
  </appenders>
  <loggers>
    <root level="all">
      <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
      <appender-ref ref="File"/>
    </root>
  </loggers>
</configuration>
```

However, the log file that gets created is: **Server-${date}.log**

My app runs under OSX, not sure that is the cause.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Property Substitution](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution) chapter in the Log4j2 Configuration Page

> date: Inserts the current date and/or time **using the specified format**

So you just have to add a date format to your property.

```
... <File name="File" fileName="logs/Server-${date:yyyy-MM-dd}.log"> ...
```

The name of your file would be **Server-2014-05-06.log**.

You can visit the [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class from the Java Api to see all formatting possibilities.